# Is there a way to run a downloaded powershell script as admin without setting a global ExecutionPolicy bypass?

Tags: powershell

Since the `20H2` build of Windows 10 came out, if I want to run a script without copying and pasting it into a PowerShell window, I have to write the following command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Scope Process -Force
```

I don't want to turn off the default behavior, since it prevents scripts from being run by accident or maliciously.

But I'd also like to be able to just open a PowerShell window as my administrator account, and execute `.\somescript.ps1` so that it runs.

Is it secure to place the line above in my [powershell profile](https://superuser.com/questions/1090141/does-powershell-have-any-sort-of-bashrc-equivalent) so I don't have to manually run it every time I open Powershell as my Admin account, provided I still have UAC turned on (a.k.a. still have to type my password when opening a Powershell as Admin)?

Comment: That does not answer your question, but Microsoft recommends the following command instead: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.1) `-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Scope Process` you simply temporarily bypass the default setting in the scope of current process. You can see the default policies from [about_Execution_Policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.1): `Restricted` prevents execution of all scripts whereas `AllSigned` and `RemoteSigned` required the scripts to be signed by a trusted publisher, respectively.

To avoid running this command every time, still preventing all scripts from running freely, you could change your global policy to allow running signed scripts.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy AllSigned -Scope LocalMachine
```

After that you could [create a code signing certificate](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-sign-windows-powershell-scripts-with-an-enterprise-windows-pki-part-1-of-2/) and [sign your trusted PowerShell scripts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-sign-windows-powershell-scripts-with-an-enterprise-windows-pki-part-2-of-2/) with it.